# Use External Google Sheets Add-on Function inside Custom Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I installed an Add-on for Google Sheets which has a function `myAddOnFunction` that I can call in any cell and it works great and shows the value I expect.

I am writing my own custom function in the script editor and want to call `myAddOnFunction()` there for some calculations, but when I try to call it I get a `ReferenceError`.

How can I access `myAddOnFunction()` inside script editor?

Comment: Related (from [so]) : [Expose functions in a Spreadsheets Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28140533/1595451)

Comment: What's the point of linking a question which has no answers @Ruben ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you cannot access `myAddOnFunction()` programmatically.

However, what you could try is simply inserting the necessary text into your target cell. For example:

```
var cell = yourRange.getCell(1, 17);
cell.setValue('=myAddOnFunction(yourParameters)');
```

If the add-on is designed to execute functions when present in cells, inputting that string into a cell would trigger the add-on.